# What can NGOs do so that they're not infiltrated by corporate interests or agents who represent the government?

Tags: ngos

What can NGOs do so that they're not infiltrated by corporate interests or agents who represent the government? What are the mechanisms and procedures used to insure that corporate interests or agents who represent the government are kept out of a NGOs? Do these mechanisms exists within the non-profits themselves, or are some of these mechanisms dependent on an external organization or group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are familiar with the term [astroturf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing) in a political context. The key for a NGO to prevent that is transparency and reputation.

Whenever someone volunteers to help the NGO, or wants to donate, the existing NGO members can watch what is going on. Auditors watch the finances. The elected leadership is challenged from time to time by other, credible candidates. This cannot prevent infiltration by surveillance agents, but it can limit the actions of influence agents.

Comment: Many NGOs seem to have no "public" membership base, just a self perpetuating board of directors. And some have no rules against taking money from governments or arms manufacturers, but claim to give "independent" advice on foreign policy.

Comment: @KeithMcClary, there are situations where releasing the membership lists would have severe consequences for the members. So the question is, is there *internal* accountability, and what is the reputation of the NGO? Is that reputation deserved? Just because a couple of people call themselves an NGO does not make them reputable, that takes hard work.